# Как отправить POST запрос с NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Как отправить запрос multipart/form-data через метод POST с сервера NodeJS через библиотеку http || https?

Не могу понять где ставить тело запроса, оно вроде хранится в заголовках но найти не могу в документации Node JS и developer mozilla.

Мне подсказали как делать Get запросы, но с Post есть небольшие трудности.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506987/13578169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно [так](https://flaviocopes.com/node-http-post/)

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'flaviocopes.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Если мультипарт то можно [так](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/40c9284e91d209356395b43022ffc5cc)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
    url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
    formData: {
        file: fs.createReadStream('sample.zip'),
        token: '### access token ###',
        filetype: 'zip',
        filename: 'samplefilename',
        channels: 'sample',
        title: 'sampletitle',
    },
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Или другой пример [отсюда](https://wanago.io/2019/03/18/node-js-typescript-6-sending-http-requests-understanding-multipart-form-data/)

```
import * as FormData from 'form-data';
import { request } from 'http';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
 
const readStream = createReadStream('./photo.jpg');
 
const form = new FormData();
form.append('photo', readStream);
form.append('firstName', 'Marcin');
form.append('lastName', 'Wanago');
 
const req = request(
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '5000',
    path: '/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: form.getHeaders(),
  },
  response => {
    console.log(response.statusCode); // 200
  }
);
 
form.pipe(req);
```

Comment: это не мультипарт

Comment: Добавил пример из статьи

Comment: можно и так, хотя автор ('request'-а) счел 'request' устаревшим

Comment: Может последний вариант?