# react js express js отправка уведомления в telegram bot

Tags: reactjs, express

Ребята, на работе уволился веб разработчик и мне поставили задачу сделать чтобы при отправке формы данные с нее приходили не только на почту, но и в телеграм бота. Будь это php решил бы задачу за 3 минуты. Но так как с react вообще не знаком, профан, то прошу помощи здесь. Отнекиваться от задачи не получится. Вот что есть от прошлого разработчика:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.all('/mail', async (req,res) => { // не знаю как это правильно называется, но назову это функцией, и так, в этой функции происходит отправка данные с формы на почту
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    const userName = req.body.userName;
    const userPhone = req.body.userPhone;
    const pageTitle = req.body.pageTitle;
    try {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.yandex.ru",
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: 'user',
                pass: 'password',
            },
        });

        const msg = {
            from: '"No reply" <admin@*****.com>',
            to: "info@*****.com", // list of receivers
            subject: "Заявка с сайта", // Subject line
            text: `Имя - ${userName}  |   Телефон - ${userPhone}   |   Страница - ${pageTitle}`, // plain text body
        }
        
        const info = await transporter.sendMail(msg);

        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
        console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        res.send(`${msg.text}`);
        
        // Я пробовал написать это, но, естественно, это не сработало
http.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot*****/sendMessage?chat_id=-****&parse_mode=HTML&text=test message");
    
        
        
        
    }catch(e){
        res.json({
            message: `${JSON.stringify(e)}`
        })
    }

})
```

Данные на почту приходят, а вот в тг бота нет. Прошу, очень, помогите решить этот вопрос.

Comment: React тут вообще не задействован, это приложение NodeJS) естественно запрос на сервер ТГ у вас не отправился, у вас даже не импортирован http) + вы отправляете метод post параметрами get.. в общем, почитайте тут например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171742/Как-отправить-post-запрос-с-nodejs

Comment: + что за прикол делать так `res.send(\`${msg.text}\`);` если достаточно так `res.send(msg.text);` и такое же далее по коду..

Comment: @Jour спасибо, попробую, по остальным замечаниям не могу как либо прокомментировать